# javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie vs javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie , What is the difference?

Tags: java, api, rest, cookies, jax-rs

I found two classes in JAX-RS API `javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie` and `javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie`. What are the advantages of one over another?
I would like to know Which one is recommended to use and when?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not about *recommended*, it's about *appropriate*. One is for a request, and one is for a response. You can see the two different javadocs.

[`Cookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html)

> Represents the value of a HTTP cookie, transferred in a **request**.

[`NewCookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/NewCookie.html)

> Used to create a new HTTP cookie, transferred in a **response**.

`NewCookie`, when sent in the `Response`, will set a `Set-Cookie` *response* header with the cookie information, and `Cookie` will set the `Cookie` *request* header with the cookie information. This is per the HTTP spec.

Example usage:

```
@GET
public Response get() {
    return Response.ok("blah")
            .cookie(new NewCookie("foo-cookie", "StAcKoVeRfLoW2020"))
            .build();
}

[..]

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client
        .target("https://cookieurl.com/api/some-resource")
        .request()
        .cookie(new Cookie("foo-cookie", "StAcKoVeRfLoW2020"))
        .get();

@Path("some-resource")
public class SomeResource {

    @POST
    public Response post(@CookieParam("foo-cookie") Cookie cookie) {
    }
}
```

Normally on the client side, you wouldn't manually create the `Cookie` as I did. Most of time you would get the cookies from the response of an initial request, then send those cookies back. This means that in the `Response`, you will have `NewCookie`s and you you need to turn those into `Cookie`s for the next request. This can easily be accomplished by calling `newCookie.toCookie()`

```
Map<String, NewCookie> cookies = response.getCookies();
Invocation.Builder ib = target.request();
for (NewCookie cookie: cookies.values()) {
    ib.cookie(cookie.toCookie());
}
Response response = ib.get();
```