# Restful service response not setting the Set-Cookie header

Tags: java, rest, cookies, jax-rs

Does the Rest Service Response use the **Cookie** header of the Request from Client ?

I am getting 2 Cookie headers from Request but those cookies are not being set to the Response.

How can I pass the same Cookies through Response and those 2 cookies need to be present in Client Browser ?

Comment: Cookie for a RESTful Service sounds really off because RESTful Services are meant to be Stateless. What is your requirement?

Comment: Look here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api I think cookies are something against restful

Comment: @Shazin, I need to add **Set-Cookie** header to Response and it should be present in Client Browser.

Comment: Create `NewCookie`s and set it in the `Response`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34046292/2587435) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/NewCookie.html#NewCookie-javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie-)