# Rest Jersey client how to pass cookie in all requests

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

Is there a nice way to pass cookie to all request that use same Client object?
Right now I must pass cookie to every request like this:

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
UriBuilder authenticate_url = UriBuilder.fromUri("xxxxxxxxx/authenticate");

WebTarget webTarget = client.target(authenticate_url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();


Map<String, NewCookie> cookies = response.getCookies(); //store cookies

webTarget = client.target(other_url);       
invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).cookie(cookies.get("KEY"));

response = invocationBuilder.get(); //works

invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

response = invocationBuilder.get(); //does not work
```

Comment: [Use a ClientRequestFilter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). I think the cookie map un the ClientRequestContext might be unmodifiable though. You might need to just set the `Cookie` header manually.

Comment: As an aside, the cookie map from the response returns `NewCookie`s. This is only from server to client. Client to server should use `Cookie`. You  can turn a `NewCookie` to a `Cookie` by calling `newCookie.toCookie()`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34046292/2587435

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use @Context like this

```
@GET
public String get(@Context HttpHeaders hh) 
{

MultivaluedMap<String, String> headerParams = hh.getRequestHeaders();
    Map<String, Cookie> pathParams = hh.getCookies(); 
}
```

or you can use `@CookieParam` annotation like so

```
@POST
public void post(@CookieParam("<parmeter name>") CookieParameter ckparameter) {

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your invocation Builder add

```
invocationBuilder.header("Cookie", "example-cookie=hello world;exapmle2-cookie=hai all");
```

Comment: I am asking about client only.

Comment: I tried invocationBuilder.header("Cookie", cookies.get("KEY"));
but it wasn't accepted by the server
because the actual request happens at webTarget.request

Comment: cookies.get("KEY") will return only the value in cookie with key "KEY" use "KEY="+cookies.get("KEY")  instead and try again