# How to Maintain state Jersey Client Using java

Tags: java, session, cookies, get, jersey

How to Maintain state Jersey Client

```
    { //
      //      Some session logic 
      //
     } 
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget baseTarget =
        client.target("https");
        /
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new 
        MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
        formData.add("usr", "@gmail.com");
        formData.add("pwd", "mat");
        Response response = baseTarget.request().post(Entity.form(formData))  
        System.out.println("----Second-time--method invoked GET-------");

        Response resp_sec = base2Target.request().get(); //second time in session perform action client side
```

See if this Helps.This code provides me a template.hope it works for you.

Comment: I hope you aren't writing your real login password here!

Comment: I have changed my credential ,security .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the cookies from the initial response. These will be `NewCookie` instances, which are the cookies that the server sends to the client, as `Set-Cookie` headers. On the client side, you need to send a `Cookie` back to the server, which will result in a `Cookie` header being sent. If you try to set a `NewCookie` on the client, it would set a `Set-Cookie` header, which would be wrong. You can easily convert a `NewCookie` to a `Cookie` simply by calling `newCookie.toCookie()`

```
Map<String, NewCookie> cookies = response.getCookies();
Invocation.Builder ib = baseTarget.request();
for (NewCookie cookie: cookies.values()) {
    ib.cookie(cookie.toCookie());
}
Response response = ib.get();
```

**See also:**

- [javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie vs javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie , What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34046292/2587435)

Comment: How to Convert Java JERSEY Response object (which contains JSON ) to JAVA Class
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894972/how-to-convert-java-jersey-response-object-which-contains-json-to-java-class