# How to Convert Java JERSEY Response object (which contains JSON ) to JAVA Class()

Tags: java, json, parsing, jersey, response

1. How to Convert Response Object (Java JERSEY ) which contains JSON  to JAVA Class()

   ```
    Client client =ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target= client.target("https://shoa.enext.com/api/resource/Sales%20Invoice");
    Response response = target.request().get();
   ```
2. in Response JSON data is fetch which is as Follows:

   ```
    {"home_page":"/desk","message":"Logged In","full_name":"Shoaib Shaikh"}
   ```
3. A HOW to access Different Fields of JSON
4. How to convert/parse this JSON Data Into Java Class and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

Comment: Let me try it . Will get back for your feedback. :)