# Get SecurityContext for Dropwizard integration tests

Tags: java, angular, session, liquibase, dropwizard

I'm writing integration tests for my `Dropwizard` + `Liquibase` + `Angular` application to test the REST service.
My app has basic authentication with cookies.

So I've created ClassRule:

```
@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<RESTServerConfiguration> RULE =
            new DropwizardAppRule<>(RESTServer.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("serverconfig.yml"));
```

When I test the `login` method:

```
final Response response = RULE.client().target("http://localhost:" + RULE.getLocalPort() + "/api/users/login")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.json("{\"username\": \"admin\", \"password\": \"admin\"}"));
```

everything works fine.

But when I try to test the protected resource, e.g.:

```
final TestResponse response = RULE.client().target("http://localhost:" + RULE.getLocalPort() + "/api/users/getAllUsers")
    .request()
    .get(TestResponse.class);
```

it fails with 401 error.

How can I get SecurityContext or store the session somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this thing out.

All I needed to do is to extract cookies from `login` request, such as:

`

```
String cookieValue = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, NewCookie> entry : loginResponse.getCookies().entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if ("sessionToken".equals(key)) {
        cookieValue = entry.getValue().toString();
        cookieValue = cookieValue.substring(0, cookieValue.indexOf(";"));
    }
}
```

`

and then set it as a header to the protected resource request, such as:

.header("Cookie", cookieValue)

Comment: You don't need to do all that. You can use `.cookie(entry.getValue().toCookie())`. And why even loop? Just do a map.get and check for a null. or if you just want to send all the cookies, something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878059/2587435

Comment: @peeskillet You're right, thanks for the comment. The loop is useless indeed.